# Absolute positioning regardless of content width

Tags: html, css, position, width

### Summary

*You can access the example [here](https://rawgit.com/LNFWebsite/Streamly/master/index.html), or [on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121172618/https://rawgit.com/LNFWebsite/Streamly/master/index.html) if the first link is broken.*

I am trying to align an element containing a video's time superimposed on an image. I have aligned it using `position: absolute` and `left: 81px`. The time usually consists of 4 characters (ex. `3:33`) leaving a consistent width for the element.

[image: Example 1]

However, when the time is more than 4 characters (ex. `13:33`), the entire element moves to the right.

[image: Example 2]

*[Here's a codepen of this specific element](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rObJQd). Just play around with the content of `#nextVideoTime`.*

### Question

How can I absolutely position an element regardless of the width of the content?

*Please note that the parent element has a percentage width, so I can't use `right: 280px` instead...*

Comment: maybe you could build a fiddle or codepen with the relevant codes, it will help you to get some answers :)

Comment: Just added a codepen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `#nextVideoTime` Remove style `left`

and Add

```
width:98px;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:right;
```

Comment: It seems that when the overall width of the window changes, the time moves independently: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpvQaa I'm going to try tweaking it on my own...

Comment: I tweaked it, and used an absolute width instead of the percentage, it worked! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbZrZr

Comment: Just replace your `width:27%` with `width:98px` and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer it this way:

Added a div for image and time.

HTML

```
<div id="nextVideo" onclick="forwardVideo();">
  <span class="fa fa-forward"></span>
  <div class="container">
    <img id="nextVideoImage" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/5y_KJAg8bHI/default.jpg">
    <p id="nextVideoTime">13:15</p>
  </div>
  <p id="nextVideoName">Avicii - Wake Me Up (Lyric Video)</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
#nextVideoTime {
  bottom: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  right: 2px;
}
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmQErB).

Comment: I like your method too, except it's more complication and data than is really necessary. Since the picture doesn't change size, I'm going to just go for the `text-align` method. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Unless I have to add other elements that will be superimposed on the image. Both methods are valid HTML... I think...

Answer (score -1):

you may use width and text-align:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#nextVideo {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 75px;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: initial;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#nextVideoImage {
  height: inherit;
  float: left;
}

#nextVideoName {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
}

#nextVideoName {
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
/*----- IMPORTANT PART -----*/

#nextVideoTime {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  width:45%;
  text-align:right;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="nextVideo" onclick="forwardVideo();">
  <span class="fa fa-forward"></span>
  <img id="nextVideoImage" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/5y_KJAg8bHI/default.jpg">
  <p id="nextVideoName">Avicii - Wake Me Up (Lyric Video)</p>
  <p id="nextVideoTime">33:15</p>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EVJQrp